# How to change Play Store update settings from inside of an Android app

Tags: android, mobile, google-play

I would like to change the way Play Store updates my application. That is, I want to allow users to choose whether to download updates via WiFi or / and mobile network, without having to leave my app.

Is it possible to change the settings of the Play Store from within my application? And if so, how? Is there any type of Intent, that allows me to check and change these settings?

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No, it is not possible to change playstore settings from your application, instead you can send user to playstore settings whenever he wants to change the update settings.
>   
> you can do this by using below code

```
try {
  Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.android.finsky.activities.SettingsActivity");
  intent.setClassName("com.android.vending", "com.google.android.finsky.activities.SettingsActivity");
  startActivity(intent);
}
catch(Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```